# Heroku Deploy not cannot find tmi.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my twitch chatbot to heroku.
I can run it normally using `node main.js` in cmd.

```
2020-07-13T12:18:52.325944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node main.js`
2020-07-13T12:18:55.572924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-07-13T12:18:55.695565+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490284+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490415+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490416+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490417+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490423+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'tmi.js'
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490424+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490424+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/main.js
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490430+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490434+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490435+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490435+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/main.js:1:13)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490435+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490436+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490436+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490436+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490440+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490450+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490451+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/main.js' ]
2020-07-13T12:18:55.490451+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

i checked in heroku bash, all are in the same directory
ProcFile main.js node_modules package.json package-lock.json

i tried replacing `const tmi = require('tmi.js');`
with
`const tmi = require('./tmi.js');`
`const tmi = require('./node_modules/tmi.js');`
`const tmi = require('node/modules/tmi.js');`

i also tried putting `/node_modules` in a gitignore file

i have a ProcFile with
`web: node main.js`
which Heroku Dyno is set to.

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Gian",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Thank you for any/all your answers.

Comment: Share your `package.json` as well as your build log. (The log where it says it's installing your npm packages.)

Comment: if you mean npm install tmi.js here it is `npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, seehttps://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN bot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ tmi.js@1.5.0
updated 1 package and audited 51 packages in 5.818s
found 0 vulnerabilities`
it is the same in heroku when i tried to heroku run `npm install tmi.js`

Comment: No. I don*t mean that. Your `package.json` is incomplete. It needs to have `dependencies`. https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file#:~:text=To%20add%20dependencies%20and%20devDependencies,save%2Ddev%20flag%20for%20devDependencies.